# How to make infinite circle tabs?

Tags: flutter

I'm using typical tabs solution (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs) and I have to make swipes infinite and circle.

Example (3 tabs): Tab1->Tab2->Tab3->Tab1->Tab2... etc

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think not directly with TabBar, but you might do your own custom TabBar :) Using ListView.builder with horizontal direction, without itemCount... (obviously you have to add your own item Widgets with onTap or GestureDetector, etc).

```
class SampleInfiniteTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleInfiniteTabsState createState() => _SampleInfiniteTabsState();
}

class _SampleInfiniteTabsState extends State<SampleInfiniteTabs> {
  List<Tab> tabs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabs = List.generate(
        10,
        (idx) => Tab(
              child: Text("My Tab $idx"),
            ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: MyCustomTabBar(
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomTabBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final List<Widget> tabs;

  static const double kTabBarHeight = 80;

  const MyCustomTabBar({Key key, this.tabs}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: buildTabs(),
      height: kTabBarHeight,
    );
  }

  buildTabs() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
        var tab = tabs[idx % tabs.length];
        return Container(
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: tab,
        );
      },
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize {
    return Size.fromHeight(kTabBarHeight);
  }
}
```